# Appcrash popup not showing?

Tags: windows-7, windows, debug, windows-error-reporting

So i have 2 almost identical machines.

Both on Win7 64bit, but one has a quadro M4000 and the other a p4000 and different motherboards and that's about the only differences.

I am trying to check CDB is logging correctly, now on machine 1, if i crash a program it pops up, "Program.exe has stopped working", which is fine.

However on the other machine I have CDB enable to dump logs but i never get that program has stopped working message.
So the program crashes instantly and then i see the cmd popup dumping the log file, but not "Blahblah.exe has stopped working".

I have checked local group policy settings and registry to make sure windows error logging isn't disabled and as far as i can tell the machines settings are identical.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was installing the CDB debugging tools that was disabling the message pop-up.
CDB takes over the popup because where as usually the program would crash, show the app crash error and you get to decide what happens next, with CDB being installed it overrules that and runs a cmd which the dumps a error log file to the specified place.